# Whats this function returns Boolean?

Tags: solidity

I don't understand why these types of functions have to return a Boolean.

```
function becomeRichest() public payable returns (bool) {
    if (msg.value > mostSent) {
        richest = msg.sender;
        mostSent = msg.value;
        amount += msg.value;
        players++;
        return true;
    } else {
        amount += msg.value;
        players++;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `returns` with functions marked `payable`. They will always return the `transaction hash`.

Comment: That is the question. I copied this code from the following place:
https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/7283
and I didn't understand why the Boolean was returned.

Comment: There is no bool in the current version of the code https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/docs/common-patterns.rst

Comment: @IftifarTaz That's not correct. Payable functions can certainly return values. You may be thinking about the fact that _transactions_ don't have return values, so calling such a function from outside the blockchain wouldn't give you access to the return value. But if you call from another contract, you will receive the return value as you would expect.

Comment: @smarx my bad. thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you for your answers, then, to clarify myself better ... On what grounds was that Boolean return placed?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how are you going to interact with it. For example, if you are interacting with this contract by using [truffle](https://www.trufflesuite.com), then you could see something like this:

```js
let richest = await contractInstance.becomeRichest({ value: 1000 })
```

As you can see, it returns the return value in that function.